# Using a menu to select the duration for an Android Countdown timer

Tags: android, timer, popup, menuitem, countdowntimer

I am trying to allow the user to select the duration of the countdown timer from a popup menu.  I am sure I am missing something simple, but I am just not seeing it.  Every time I run it like this, the countdown timer is immediately finished.  It looks like I am not passing the duration at all and the timeLeft is just passing as 0. You may also see from the problem that I am not too experience yet, so please be gentle.

```
int timeLeft;

final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(timeLeft, 1000);

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.countdownMenu1:
            timeLeft = 15000;
            timer.start();
            return true;

        case R.id.countdownMenu2:
            timeLeft = 20000;
            timer.start();
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}

public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer  {

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // textViewTime.setText("Completed.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are instantiating your CounterClass before setting the value of timerLeft. Now, as the initial values are set to 0 in java, you are starting timer with 0 seconds left.

You can do something like this :

```
class CounterClass

    int timerLeft;

....
```

And to set the value to it.

```
timer.timerLeft = 15000;
```

Comment: I had no luck with that.  Perhaps I didn't do it right but I was getting a long list of issues when I tried that.  Thank you though.

Comment: Show the code and errors. And try logging the value of timerLeft just before starting it.